# Calculating the occupied resources at that time?

Tags: excel

I have four columns in excel, namely:

1. Start time of app
2. End time of app
3. Occupied resources

For example,

```
Start time    End time    Occupied resources

0             30          10
20            70          10
30            50          25
```

From this information, I have to generate information about the total occupied resources in the system against the time.

So against the start of each application, what is the number of occupied resources at that time? I cannot do a simple summation of the third column because the application leaves the resources at the end time. Any suggestions ?

**EDIT**

My expected output would be a fourth column that states the number of occupied resources at that "starttime". So for my example above, the output would be:

Start time TotalOccupiedAfterStart    End time    Occupied resources

```
0              10                       30          10
20             20                       70          10
30             35                       50          25
```

So at start time '0' the first application gets 10 resources. At start time '20', the second application gets 10 resources. The state of the system at this time is 20 because the first application has not ended according to its endtime. At start time 30, the third application gets 25 resources but we see that the first application ended at "30" and the second application is still running according to its end time. So the total occupied resources at starttime 30 are 25.

Comment: Could you add the expected output to your question? If you want to get for each line the resources occupied at start (in your example: 10, 20, 45) you should be able to use SUMIFS: `SUMIFS([occupied], [start],"<="&[@start], [end],">="&[@end])`

Comment: @hsan What is "occupied","start","@start","end","@end" in your formula ? Are these column names ? What is the difference between "start" and "@start" ?

Comment: I used the syntax for table references to avoid making the formula incredibly long. `[abc]` would be the column named abc, `[@abc]` would be the cell in the current row in the column named abc.

Comment: @hsan thanks for your answer. Did you see my example ? Will this formula achieve the same output ? If so, then please put it in an answer so I can choose it as the best answer.

Comment: Ok, then you'll only need to substitute the ">=" with ">" in the last bit of the formula. I have submitted an answer with the adjusted formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SUMIFS` with two conditions (start time, and end time) will give you the result you are looking for. `SUMIFS` takes as the first argument the range to sum up; the second (4th, 6th, 8th...) argument is the criteria range (this range will be checked agains the criteria); the third (5th, 7th, 9th...) argument is the criteria itself (either the value you are looking for in the criteria range, or a string with a comparison operator, e.g. "<10").

Assuming the data shown in your question is a table the following formula uses [structured references / table formulas](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-structured-references-in-Excel-table-formulas-75fb07d3-826a-449c-b76f-363057e3d16f). The formula for the column `TotalOccupiedAfterStart` should be:

```
=SUMIFS([Occupied resources], [Start time], "<="&[@[Start time]], [End time], ">"&[@[Start time]])
```

**EDIT: expanded to give a more detailed explanation**

We want to calculate the sum of all the values in `[Occupied resources]` where the current line's `[@[Start time]]` is within the range of `[Start time]` and `[End time]`. This is the perfect job of Excel's `SUMIFS` which Excel describes as follows:

> `SUMIFS(sum_range, criteria_range1, criteria1, ...)`
>
> Adds the cells specified by a given set of conditions or criteria.

The first argument is the range containing the values we want to sum up. So we provide here the column `[Occupied resources]`. For the rest of the arguments `SUMIFS` always requires pairs: the range to be checked (*criteria_range*), and the value or condition to test that range against (*criteria*).

To see if a line's start time is between another line's start and end time we need to check that two conditions are met:

1. the current (app1) start time must be greater or equal to the start time of the line we are testing (app2) *= app2 was started before or at the same time as app1*
2. the current start time must be less than the end time of the line we are testing *= app2 was closed after app1 was started*

So for the first condition the range that needs to be checked (*criteria_range*) is the column with all the start times and "less-than-or-equal-to current start time" is the criteria. Our first set of *criteria_range* and *criteria* is:

```
[Start time], "<="&[@[Start time]]
```

For the second condition the range that needs to be checked is the column with all the end times and "greater-than current start time" is the criteria. That makes the second set of *criteria_range* and *criteria*:

```
[End time], ">"&[@[Start time]]
```

Putting it all together we have

1. the range with the values to be summed up
2. the range of values to be checked for the first condition
3. the first condition
4. the range of values to be checked for the second condition
5. the second condition

=

```
=SUMIFS(
    range with the values to be summed up,
    
    range of values to be checked for the first condition,
    first condition,
    
    range of values to be checked for the second condition,
    second condition
)
```

=

```
=SUMIFS(
    [Occupied resources],
    
    [Start time],
    "<="&[@[Start time]],
    
    [End time],
    ">"&[@[Start time]]
)
```

Comment: There are mistakes in your formula. I am getting errors

Comment: You're right. I missed closing a string. Edited to fix that, the formula should work now.

Comment: I have added a more detailed explanation. Does this cover it or did I skip something that is unclear?

Answer (score 1):

If your Start time, End time and Occupied Resources are in columns A, B and C starting at row 2, the total resources would be

```
=SUMIFS(C$2:C$9,A$2:A$9,"<="&A2,B$2:B$9,">"&A2)
```

i.e. the start and end time of each application are compared to the start time of the current row.

Whether you put >= or > depends if you consider the first application to be still running at t=30 or to have just finished.

[image]

Comment: Shouldnt the last parameter be B2 instead of A2?

Comment: I don't think so because you only want to see if the start time of the current row (A2) is between the start time and end time of any of the rows.

Comment: Could you maybe explain the entire formula to me ? I already chose one answer but have an upvote for your effort.

Comment: Thanks! The formula says 'add up all the values in cells C2:C9 where the start times (A2:A9) in the same row are less than or equal to A2 and the finish times B2:B9 are greater than A2'. For row 2, it only counts itself because only 0 is >=0 and <30. For row 3, it counts the first two because 20 is  >=0 and <30 and also >=20 and <70.